# Stuck in a problem involving circumcentres and orthocentres

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> In an acute-angled triangle $\triangle ABC$, a point $D$ lies on the segment $BC$. Let $O_1$ and ​$O_2$​ denote the circumcentres of $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$, respectively. Prove that the line joining the circumcentre of $ΔABC$ and the orthocentre of $\triangle DO_1O_2$ is parallel to $BC$.

Let the orthocentre be $K$.
I have proved $O, K, O_1, O_2, A$ are concyclic.
I just need to prove $\angle AO_2O=\angle ADB$.

[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: Your plan is correct. As you have proved $A,O,O_1,K,O_2$ are concyclic; 

$\angle AKO=\angle AO_2O=\dfrac12\angle AO_2C=180^\circ-\angle ADC=\angle ADB.$

Hence $OK\parallel BC.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A, O_1, O, K$ and $O_2$ are indeed cyclic but I will only use that $A, O, K$ and $O_2$ are cyclic. As you have already shown it, I will proceed from there.

As $\triangle AO_2C$ and $\triangle AOC$ are both isosceles, $OO_2$ is perpendicular bisector of $AC$.

So, $\angle O_2 O C = \frac 12 \angle AOC = \angle B$

$\angle KOO_2 = \angle KAO_2 = 90^\circ - \angle C$

$\angle KOC = \angle O_2 O C -  \angle KOO_2 = 90^\circ - \angle A = \angle OCB$

$\therefore ~OK \parallel BC$

---

To show $A, O, K$ and $O_2$ are cyclic, I used the fact that $\angle AO_1D = 2 \angle B$ and $AD \perp O_1O_2$. That leads to $\angle AKO_2 = 90^\circ - \angle O_1O_2K = \angle B = \angle AOO_2$

Comment: [+1] You might be interested by the duplicate answer I have found (indicated upwards).

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. I just went through the link - indeed similar angle chasing.

Comment: @MathLover I follow everything, but how did you get $90^\circ - \angle A = \angle OCB$?

Comment: @Eisentein - because $\angle BOC = 2 \angle A$ and $OB = OC$